# Cannot get path from custom ID property made with RNA

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

`bpy.context.active_pose_bone.path_from_id("RegisteredIDProperty")`

is used to access Registered ID properties. What would I have to do to access a Custom ID property?

`bpy.context.active_pose_bone.path_from_id("CustomIDProperty")`

does not seem to work in this case, I can't seem to find people running into my issue either.

I plan on assigning this to a driver later on.

````
        obj = bpy.context.active_pose_bone
        
        if self.x_rotincui:
            
            obj.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
            rna_idprop_ui_create(
                obj,
                "increments", 
                default = 10,
                min=0, max=360,
                soft_min=None, soft_max=None,
                description="A",
                overridable=False,
                subtype=None,
                )
            Xpath = obj.path_from_id("increments")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Change Xpath with

```
Xpath = obj.path_from_id() + "[\"increment X\"]"
```